# Cannot find Kotlin code format in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Does anyone know why I don't see the Kotlin in the settings [(settings image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFO1M.png). Or how I can change Kotlin code formatting in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `reforma` from the settings filter on the top left. You should see all the languages listed:

[image: Kotlin]

Also check you have Kotlin plug-in enabled and installed.